# MultiThreading Async

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why does this code not reach the Console.WriteLine("Other thread is done!"); ? This code is from Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework book, pg 717-718.

```
        private static AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID of thread in Main(): {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        AddParms data = new AddParms(3, 4);
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Add));
        t.Start(data);

        waitHandle.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Other thread is done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Add(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID of thread in Add(): {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        AddParms ap = (AddParms)data;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", ap.A, ap.B, ap.A + ap.B);
    }
```

Comment: There is no code setting the event e.g 'waitHandle.Set()' so it waits infinitely on waitHandle.WaitOne()

Answer (score 1):

```
waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

This line causes the execution to stop until the wait handle is set.
The provided code never sets that wait handle, and thus the code blocks indefinitely.